# Solr search and score across both parent and child documents

Tags: solr

I'm setting up a Solr collection to search contact information. The data model, as it is now, consists of parties that have contact methods. I've implemented this using Solr idea of nested documents. (I can try to change it into a totally flat model if this is a better solution.) I want to run a single simple query typed by users against both parties and their contact methods, but only get back the parties.

I've seem to have managed it so:

```
_query_:"{!edismax qf=p1 p2 p3 ... pn v=$TERMS}" 
_query_:"{!parent which="type:party"}{!edismax qf=m1 m2 m3 ... mn
          v=$TERMS}"
```

Here `p1`...`pn` are party fields, `m1`...`mn` are contact method fields, and `TERMS` is the user query, same for both. I use the `sow` parameter to split `TERMS` into tokens and `tie=1.0` to make the overall score of a single `_query_` a sum of its components.

Questions:

1. Is this the right way to set it up?
2. If yes (or if there's a better way) how do I get the overall score of the query to be the sum of its two halves? Right now it seems to use the max score, i.e. if `TERMS` are `P M`, `P` matches one of `p` fields, and `M` matches one of `M`, the final score is based either on one, or on another; the other is computed, but zeroed.

Here's the relevant snippet from the explanation:

```
"document-123":{
   "match":true, "value":9.41881, "description":"sum of:",
   "details":[
     {"match":true, "value":9.41881, ... },
     {"match":true, "value":0.0,
      "description":"Score based on 1 child docs ..., best match:",
      "details":[{"match":true, "value":11.7847, 
        "description":"sum of:", "details":[ ... ]}]}]},
```

I.e. the parent matches with 9+, the child with 11+, but then that child match is ignored and the final score remains 9+.

Comment: You describe what you want to implement, but it is hard glean from this what exactly you want to achieve. Do you have the false match problem described here: http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/ ? You seem to have certain ranking requirements? It will probably easier to answer if you describe your requirements rather than asking whether a certain solution matches some implicit requirements. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a "score" parameter for the "parent" query that will all you to reference the scores from the subordinate query (your edismax query).

So in your parent query, add a score parameter, and in your edismax, you may want to work with some boosts in your qf parameter, like so:

```
_query_:"{!parent which="type:party" score=total}{!edismax qf=m1^0 m2^5 m3^1 ... mn
          v=$TERMS}"
```

You can use various aggregation methods like max|min|total|avg for "score".

refs:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-Scoring
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html